# MQ: Connection to host rejected | Channel negotiation failed

Tags: java, glassfish, ibm-mq

Hello I have one big problem with connecting to IBM WebSphere MQ using JMS
I use:

- Win 7
- JDK 1.7
- IBM WebSphere MQ server 7.5.0.2
- GlassFish 4.0

I make one QueueManager named `test1` and one queue in that named `test1q` and one channel for negotiation named `test1channel`

#### My code is here:

```
StandaloneSender s = new StandaloneSender();
try{
    s.send(“hello word”);
}catch (Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

#### StandaloneSender.java

```
import javax.jms.Message;
import javax.jms.QueueConnection;
import javax.jms.QueueSender;
import javax.jms.QueueSession;
import javax.jms.Session;
import javax.naming.NamingException;

public class StandaloneSender {
    private P2PUtils utils;
    private QueueConnection connection;
    private QueueSession session;
    private QueueSender sender;
    public void send(String message) throws NamingException, JMSException, IOException {
        StandaloneSender sender = new StandaloneSender();
        sender.connect();
        sender.sendMessage(message);
        sender.disconnect();
    }

    public StandaloneSender() {
        utils = new P2PUtils();
    }

    private void connect() throws NamingException, JMSException {
        connection = utils.getConnection();
        session =
            connection.createQueueSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
        sender = session.createSender(utils.getQueue());
        System.out.println("Sender started.");
    }

    private void sendMessage(String text) throws JMSException {
        Message message = session.createTextMessage(text);
        sender.send(message);
        System.out.println(
            "Sent message <"
                + text
                + "> with ID <"
                + message.getJMSMessageID()
                + ">");
    }
    private void disconnect() throws JMSException {
        sender.close();
        session.close();
        connection.close();
        System.out.println("Sender stopped.");
    }
}
```

#### P2PUtils.java

```
import javax.jms.JMSException;
import javax.jms.Queue;
import javax.jms.QueueConnection;
import javax.jms.QueueConnectionFactory;
import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.NamingException;

public class P2PUtils extends JmsUtils {

    private static final String QCF_NAME = "test1";
    private static final String QUEUE_NAME = "test1q";

    public QueueConnection getConnection() throws NamingException, JMSException {
        Context context = getInitialContext();
        QueueConnectionFactory qcf =
            (QueueConnectionFactory) context.lookup(QCF_NAME);
        return qcf.createQueueConnection();
    }

    public Queue getQueue() throws NamingException {
        Context context = getInitialContext();
        return (Queue) context.lookup(QUEUE_NAME);
    }
}
```

#### JmsUtils.java

```
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.naming.NamingException;

public class JmsUtils {
    private static final String CF_CLASS_NAME = "com.ibm.mq.jms.context.WMQInitialContextFactory";
    private static final String WMQ_URL = "localhost:1414/SYSTEM.DEF.SVRCONN";

    protected Context getInitialContext() throws NamingException {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, CF_CLASS_NAME);
        props.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, WMQ_URL);
        return new InitialContext(props);
    }
}
```

But I have got this exception from glassfish:

```
[2014-02-17T16:35:25.286+0330] [glassfish 4.0] [SEVERE] [] [] [tid: _ThreadID=25 _ThreadName=Thread-4] [timeMillis: 1392642325286] [levelValue: 1000] [[
  javax.naming.ServiceUnavailableException: Unable to connect to the target queue manager localhost:1414/SYSTEM.DEF.SVRCONN [Root exception is com.ibm.mq.MQException: MQJE001: Completion Code '2', Reason '2539'.]
    at com.ibm.mq.jms.context.MQContext.<init>(MQContext.java:196)
    at com.ibm.mq.jms.context.WMQInitialContextFactory.getInitialContext(WMQInitialContextFactory.java:29)
    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:684)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:307)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.init(InitialContext.java:242)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.<init>(InitialContext.java:216)
    at com.surena.MQ.JmsUtils.getInitialContext(JmsUtils.java:17)
    at com.surena.MQ.P2PUtils.getConnection(P2PUtils.java:16)
    at com.surena.MQ.StandaloneSender.connect(StandaloneSender.java:32)
    at com.surena.MQ.StandaloneSender.send(StandaloneSender.java:22)
    at com.surena.servlet.MainServlet.doGet(MainServlet.java:50)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:260)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:188)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: com.ibm.mq.MQException: MQJE001: Completion Code '2', Reason '2539'.
    at com.ibm.mq.MQManagedConnectionJ11.<init>(MQManagedConnectionJ11.java:247)
    at com.ibm.mq.MQClientManagedConnectionFactoryJ11._createManagedConnection(MQClientManagedConnectionFactoryJ11.java:588)
    at com.ibm.mq.MQClientManagedConnectionFactoryJ11.createManagedConnection(MQClientManagedConnectionFactoryJ11.java:630)
    at com.ibm.mq.StoredManagedConnection.<init>(StoredManagedConnection.java:107)
    at com.ibm.mq.MQSimpleConnectionManager.allocateConnection(MQSimpleConnectionManager.java:205)
    at com.ibm.mq.MQQueueManagerFactory.obtainBaseMQQueueManager(MQQueueManagerFactory.java:911)
    at com.ibm.mq.MQQueueManagerFactory.procure(MQQueueManagerFactory.java:799)
    at com.ibm.mq.MQQueueManagerFactory.constructQueueManager(MQQueueManagerFactory.java:750)
    at com.ibm.mq.MQQueueManagerFactory.createQueueManager(MQQueueManagerFactory.java:157)
    at com.ibm.mq.MQQueueManager.<init>(MQQueueManager.java:757)
    at com.ibm.mq.pcf.PCFAgent.connect(PCFAgent.java:230)
    at com.ibm.mq.pcf.PCFAgent.<init>(PCFAgent.java:163)
    at com.ibm.mq.pcf.PCFMessageAgent.<init>(PCFMessageAgent.java:140)
    at com.ibm.mq.jms.context.MQContext.<init>(MQContext.java:183)
    ... 39 more
Caused by: com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiException: CC=2;RC=2539;AMQ9204: Connection to host 'localhost(1414)' rejected. [1=com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiException[CC=2;RC=2539;AMQ9503: Channel negotiation failed. [3=SYSTEM.DEF.SVRCONN]],3=localhost(1414),5=RemoteConnection.initSess]
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.api.RemoteFAP.jmqiConnect(RemoteFAP.java:2053)
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.api.RemoteFAP.jmqiConnect(RemoteFAP.java:1226)
    at com.ibm.mq.ese.jmqi.InterceptedJmqiImpl.jmqiConnect(InterceptedJmqiImpl.java:311)
    at com.ibm.mq.ese.jmqi.ESEJMQI.jmqiConnect(ESEJMQI.java:337)
    at com.ibm.mq.MQSESSION.MQCONNX_j(MQSESSION.java:924)
    at com.ibm.mq.MQManagedConnectionJ11.<init>(MQManagedConnectionJ11.java:236)
    ... 52 more
Caused by: com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiException: CC=2;RC=2539;AMQ9503: Channel negotiation failed. [3=SYSTEM.DEF.SVRCONN]
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteConnection.initSess(RemoteConnection.java:1111)
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteConnection.connect(RemoteConnection.java:727)
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteConnectionSpecification.getSessionFromNewConnection(RemoteConnectionSpecification.java:400)
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteConnectionSpecification.getSession(RemoteConnectionSpecification.java:299)
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteConnectionPool.getSession(RemoteConnectionPool.java:164)
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.api.RemoteFAP.jmqiConnect(RemoteFAP.java:1598)
    ... 57 more]]
```

And this from IBM MQ

```
2/17/2014 14:41:51 - Process(3924.1) User(MUSR_MQADMIN) Program(runmqlsr.exe)
                      Host(PROGRAMMER1) Installation(Installation1)
                      VRMF(7.5.0.2)
AMQ6118: An internal WebSphere MQ error has occurred (20006047)

EXPLANATION:
An error has been detected, and the MQ error recording routine has been called.
ACTION:
Use the standard facilities supplied with your system to record the problem
identifier and to save any generated output files. Use either the MQ Support
site: http://www.ibm.com/software/integration/wmq/support/, or IBM Support
Assistant (ISA): http://www.ibm.com/software/support/isa/, to see whether a
solution is already available.  If you are unable to find a match, contact your
IBM support center.  Do not discard these files until the problem has been
resolved. 
----- amqxfdcp.c : 867 --------------------------------------------------------
2/17/2014 14:41:51 - Process(3924.1) User(MUSR_MQADMIN) Program(runmqlsr.exe)
                      Host(PROGRAMMER1) Installation(Installation1)
                      VRMF(7.5.0.2)
AMQ6184: An internal WebSphere MQ error has occurred on queue manager test1    
                                      .

EXPLANATION:
An error has been detected, and the WebSphere MQ error recording routine has
been called. The failing process is process 3924.
ACTION:
Use the standard facilities supplied with your system to record the problem
identifier and to save any generated output files. Use either the MQ Support
site: http://www.ibm.com/software/integration/wmq/support/, or IBM Support
Assistant (ISA): http://www.ibm.com/software/support/isa/, to see whether a
solution is already available.  If you are unable to find a match, contact your
IBM support center.  Do not discard these files until the problem has been
resolved.
```

I used all jar file that included in MQ installation directory
please help me.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9006610/com-ibm-mq-mqexception-mqje001-completion-code-2-reason-2035

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From your exception from glassfish I've picked out the interesting bits:-

```
javax.naming.ServiceUnavailableException: Unable to connect to the target
queue manager localhost:1414/SYSTEM.DEF.SVRCONN [Root exception is
com.ibm.mq.MQException: MQJE001: Completion Code '2', Reason '2539'.


Caused by: com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiException: CC=2;RC=2539;
AMQ9204: Connection to host 'localhost(1414)' rejected.
[1=com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiException[CC=2;RC=2539;
AMQ9503: Channel negotiation failed. [3=SYSTEM.DEF.SVRCONN]],
3=localhost(1414),5=RemoteConnection.initSess]

Caused by: com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiException: CC=2;RC=2539;
AMQ9503: Channel negotiation failed. [3=SYSTEM.DEF.SVRCONN]
```

There are various hints here for you. The first is the MQRC return code 2539. You can look this up using the mqrc command line tool that comes with IBM MQ. Just type `mqrc 2539` and it will report:-

```
2539  0x000009eb  MQRC_CHANNEL_CONFIG_ERROR.
```

Also we have a couple of error messages:-

```
AMQ9204: Connection to host 'localhost(1414)' rejected.
AMQ9503: Channel negotiation failed. [3=SYSTEM.DEF.SVRCONN]
```

You can see the full error message description using the mqrc tool as well, just type `mqrc AMQ9204`. So we're getting the idea here that your network connection (channel) was not working right and the queue manager didn't like it for some reason. The next thing is to see what the queue manager had to say about it, as you did. In you error log you say you saw:-

```
2/17/2014 14:41:51 - Process(3924.1) User(MUSR_MQADMIN) Program(runmqlsr.exe)
                      Host(PROGRAMMER1) Installation(Installation1)
                      VRMF(7.5.0.2)
AMQ6118: An internal WebSphere MQ error has occurred (20006047)
```

Now this is indicating that there is likely an FDC file that has been cut as well which will give more details, but there is also another error code that you can look up, again with the mqrc tool. Type in `mqrc 0x20006047` and it will report:-

```
536895559  0x20006047. xecX_E_CONV_NOT_SUP
```

This suggests that it was unable to cope with data conversion between your client and the queue manager. The FDC file will give you more details.

Comment: Thanks a lot Morag
Your answer help me very much.

Comment: That's great @EN20. Click on the tick beside the answer to accept it as the answer to your question.

Comment: I found one important point
for connecting to MQ you must disable `channel authentication records` in Queue Manager properties or add appropriate record for connect to MQ.
and other important point is to pass `userName` and `pass` of user that has access to MQ or is in mqm group, in `connect();` method like this:
`connect(userName, password);`

Comment: Indeed so, these have been covered in other questions related to receiving error reason code 2035