# How to specify a queue manager when using PCFMessageAgent(host, port, channel) constructor?

Tags: java, ibm-mq, pcf

I am using MQ Java PCF API to retrieve information from an MQ installation.
There are several constructors for the class `PCFMessageAgent`.
There is one that accepts the `host`, `port` and `channel` name. I have shown an extract from the documentation.

```
public PCFMessageAgent(String host,
                       int port,
                       String channel)
                throws MQException
Initializes a new PCFMessageAgent with a client connection to a queue manager.
```

My question is which queue manager will this connect to? 
Is it the default queue manager?
 How do I specify the queue manager i want to connect to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need to specify queue manager, as soon as you specify host and port.
You will connect to the one listening to that port.

**Update, from IBM docs:**

> A server connection channel is a bidirectional MQI channel that is
>   used to connect a IBM WebSphere MQ client to a IBM WebSphere MQ
>   server. **The server connection channel is the server end of the
>   channel**.
>
> A client connection channel is a bidirectional MQI channel that is
>   used to connect a IBM WebSphere MQ client to a IBM WebSphere MQ
>   server. IBM WebSphere MQ Explorer also uses client connections to
>   connect to remote queue managers. **The client connection channel is
>   the client end of the channel**. When you create a client-connection
>   channel, a file is created on the computer that hosts the queue
>   manager. You must then, copy the client-connection file to the IBM
>   WebSphere MQ Client computer.

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_7.5.0/com.ibm.mq.explorer.doc/e_channels.htm

Comment: You mean the queue manager that has a listener configured for that port?

Comment: Yes, only one QM can listen to the port, because each is a separate process

Comment: why do i get a Caused by: com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiException: CC=2;RC=2540;AMQ9204: Connection to host '192.168.56.102(1433)' rejected. [1=com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiException[CC=2;RC=2540;AMQ9520: Channel not defined remotely. [3=TALOS_CLIENT_CHANNEL]],3=192.168.56.102(1433),5=RemoteConnection.analyseErrorSegment] error when i try to connect to the

Comment: Have you checked that channel of type SVRCONN named "TALOS_CLIENT_CHANNEL" exists in your target QM?

Comment: The channel is defined a client connection channel. Should it be defined as SVRCONN?

Comment: Yeah, I believe you should use SVRCONN. Just updated theanswer for sure.

Comment: Where can I find the client connection file?

Comment: Not sure which file do you mean, but you can add SVRCONN channel with a couple of clicks using MQ Explorer, or use command line as described here: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_7.5.0/com.ibm.mq.con.doc/q016750_.htm

Comment: The file mentioned in the documentation. "You must then, copy the client-connection file to the IBM WebSphere MQ Client computer."

Comment: I'm afraid the file you are talking about is "client channel definition table" aka CCDT, but it's about client-channel again. If you have created SVRCONN - you do not need to share anything with clients.

Comment: I tried with a SVRCONN channel, but i get this error com.ibm.mq.MQException: MQJE001: Completion Code '2', Reason '2035'. The channel i am trying to connect to is SYSTEM.DEF.SVRCONN.

Comment: 2035 = MQRC_NOT_AUTHORIZED, here you can find detailed answer about possible reasons: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9006610/com-ibm-mq-mqexception-mqje001-completion-code-2-reason-2035

Comment: @Ajay this was a good answer to your original question, why not accept it?  See "[What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)". Specifically accept and up vote if you found it helpful.